# Issue with selecting multiple lines of a txt document and write to new text doc in python

Tags: python

Python amateur here. I have a text file that lists information on thousands of lines and I'm trying to select a line and the following 2-3 lines based on whether they match a pattern. 
I've filtered the file down from the original to just contain the parts of the file of interest to me so my current file looks like this:

```
trig1.RESP: 
stim4: silence.wav 
trig1.RESP: 
trig6.RESP: 1 
trig1.RESP:
trig1.RESP: 
trig5.RESP: 1
stim5: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
trig6.RESP: 1
stim3: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
stim5: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
trig6.RESP: 1
```

and so on and so forth...
Basically what I'm trying to do is write every line that contains the silence.wav portion of the line and then the next two lines after it. I used the following code:

```
parsed_output = open("name-of-file-to-be-written", "w")
filtered_input = open("name-of-file-that-has-above-data", "r")
for line in filtered_input:
    if "silence.wav" in line and "trig1" in filtered_input.next():
        parsed_output.write(line)
        parsed_output.write(filtered_input.next())
parsed_output.close()
```

This works fine for the most part because it prints the silence.wav line and the line which has the response (the part I'm most interested in, the trig1 before a response at this point is less important). However the issue I run into is when the lines go:

```
stim3: silence.wav
trig1.RESP: 
stim5: silence.wav
```

Since my output will then write the stim3 (current line) and stim5 (next line after skipping the trig1), I think it moves on to the next "stim:silence.wav" and skips the stim5 because it was included in the previous command when it was written.
I want the trig6.RESP: 1 after the stim5 but my output doesn't show it for that reason I described. 
Is there a way I can get it to not skip over that stim5?

Sorry if this was really long. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Small sidenote: I'd suggest you allways close files you've opened. Best way of doing it — using `with` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this? (*completely untested*)

```
count = 3
for line in filtered_input:
    if "silence.wav" in line:
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1

    if count <= 2:
        filtered_output.write(line)
```

It's not fancy, but I think it should be pretty robust.

Comment: Oh my goodness that was so simple. It worked too! Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at translating this to psuedocode says:

```
For each (Line) {
      If Next Line is "Trig1" AND Current Line is "silence.wav"
          Log it
}
## And We're Done
```

(Feel free to correct me here)

You're missing the Trig6 because you're asking for the next line that doesn't exist. Could you rewrite it where you refer backwards instead of forwards and have that fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to use a [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) so that you can keep track of three lines at a time:

```
import collections

parsed_output = open("name-of-file-to-be-written", "w")
filtered_input = open("name-of-file-that-has-above-data", "r")

window = collections.deque([None]*3, maxlen=3)
for line in filtered_input:
    window.append(line)
    if 'silence.wav' in window[0]:
        parsed_output.write(window[0])
        # only output next two lines if they don't also contain 'silence.wav'
        if 'silence.wav' not in window[1]:
            parsed_output.write(window[1])
            if 'silence.wav' not in window[2]:
                parsed_output.write(window[2])
# following if/elif in case last or second to last line contain 'silence.wav'
if 'silence.wav' in window[1]:
    parsed_output.write(window[1])
    parsed_output.write(window[2])
elif 'silence.wav' in window[2]:
    parsed_output.write(window[2])
parsed_output.close()
```

If you provide the `maxlen` parameter to deque, then when you add additional elements to one end an element is popped off of the other end, for example:

```
>>> x = collections.deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>>> x
deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>>> x.append(4)
>>> x
deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
>>> x.append(5)
>>> x
deque([3, 4, 5], maxlen=3)
```

This allows you to iterate over the file but save the last 3 lines that you read in a convenient way, any time the first element of `window` matches your condition, just output the line that matched and the following two as long as they don't also match your condition.

Comment: This is clever, but wouldn't it write some of the lines twice?, also, there should probably be a check at the end of the loop to make sure that the second to last line shouldn't trigger a write.

Comment: Just edited to address those issues, I couldn't tell from the question whether to duplicate lines were desired or not, but they probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: Please disregard my (now deleted) comment.  It was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You should really learn the use of regular expressions (module re)
It is mandatory when one wants to analyze texts.

See what it allows to do:

```
import re

ss = """trig1.RESP: 
stim4: silence.wav 
trig1.RESP: 
trig6.RESP: 1 
trig1.RESP:
trig1.RESP: 
trig5.RESP: 1
stim5: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
trig6.RESP: 1
stim3: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
stim5: silence.wav
trig1.RESP:
trig6.RESP: 1

stim777: silence.wav
stim111: silence.wav 
trig1.RESP: 
trig6.RESP: 1
trig1.RESP: 
trig6.RESP: 1"""

pat = ('^(.+silence.wav.*)(?<! ) *\n'
       '(?:(?!.*silence.wav)(.*)(?<! ) *\n)?'
       '(?:(?!.*silence.wav)(.*)(?<! ) *)?')

RE = re.compile(pat,re.MULTILINE)

for tugr in RE.findall(ss):
    print tugr
```

result

```
('stim4: silence.wav', 'trig1.RESP:', 'trig6.RESP: 1')
('stim5: silence.wav', 'trig1.RESP:', 'trig6.RESP: 1')
('stim3: silence.wav', 'trig1.RESP:', '')
('stim5: silence.wav', 'trig1.RESP:', 'trig6.RESP: 1')
('stim777: silence.wav', '', '')
('stim111: silence.wav', 'trig1.RESP:', 'trig6.RESP: 1')
```

and then you do what you want with these tuples of lines

**pat** is a string used as a pattern for defining a regex.
**RE** is a compiled regex, it's an object which has methods **search**, **match**, **findall**, etc

Parentheses `(  )` define a group.
A group captures certain portions of text.
But `(?:  )` defines a group that doesn't catch the portion of text that it matches. It is useful to act on portion of text, for example to put qualifiers `*` or `?` or `+` at the end of a group.

When the third line has 'silence.wav', it must remain unmatched, 
and when the second line has 'silence.wav', only the first line must be matched.
That's why there is the portion `(?.*silence.wav)` in two places in the pattern.

`^` is a sign meaning 'start of string'
`^` with the flag `re.MULTILINE`  means  'start of a line'

The portions `(?<! ) *` of the pattern are there to not catch the blank spaces at the end of lines.

The point `.` in a pattern means 'any character', except the LF character

```
\n
```

And other points, on which I can answer you if you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think you're right too. Next step, learn regular expressions. Got it. :)